# tensorflow runs extremely slow inside a python for loop

Tags: tensorflow

Following code uses tensorflow library and it runs terribly slower compared to numpy library. I am aware that I am calling a function that uses tensorflow library inside python for loop (which I will parallelize with python multiprocessing later), but the code as is, runs extremely slow.

Could someone please help how I can make this code run faster? Thanks.

---

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tensorflow as tf

def Trajectory_Fun(tspan, a, b, session=None, server=None):
    # Open tensorflow session
    if session==None:
        if server==None:
            sess = tf.Session()
        else:
            sess = tf.Session(server.target)       
    else:
        sess = session
    B = np.zeros(np.size(tspan), dtype=np.float64)
    B[0] = b
    for i, t in enumerate(tspan):
        r = np.random.rand(1)
        if r>a:
            c = sess.run(tf.trace(tf.random_normal((4, 4), r, 1.0))) 
        else:
            c = 0.0 # sess.run(tf.trace(tf.random_normal((4, 4), 0.0, 1.0)))
        B[i] = c
    # Close tensorflow session
    if session==None:
        sess.close()
    return B

def main(argv):
    # Parameters
    tspan = np.arange(0.0, 1000.0)
    a = 0.1
    b = 0.0
    # Run test program
    B = Trajectory_Fun(tspan, a, b, None, None)
    print 'Done!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: you are modifying your Graph object between session.run calls which is slow. You can add all ops before first `sess.run` and call `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks for your quick response. As you may have noticed, I need the value of the variable c at each time step. Could you please clarify a bit more how I can incorporate your suggestion in my above code? I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: do something like `a=tf.random_normal((4, 4), 0.0, 1.0)` before loop start, and then do `sess.run(a)` instead

Answer (score 5):

As stated in your question, this program will give poor performance because it creates several new TensorFlow graph nodes per operation. The underlying assumption in TensorFlow is (approximately) that you'll build a graph once and then call `sess.run()` on (various parts of) it multiple times. The first time you run a graph is relatively expensive, because TensorFlow has to build various data structures and optimize the execution of the graph across multiple devices.
However, TensorFlow caches this work, so subsequent uses are much cheaper.

You can make this program much faster by constructing the graph once and using (e.g.) a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) op to feed in the value that changes in each iteration. For example, the following should do the trick:

```
B = np.zeros(np.size(tspan), dtype=np.float64)
B[0] = b

# Define the TensorFlow graph once and reuse it in each iteration of the for loop.
r_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
out_t = tf.trace(tf.random_normal((4, 4), r_placeholder, 1.0))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for i, t in enumerate(tspan):
    r = np.random.rand(1)
    if r > a:
      c = sess.run(out_t, feed_dict={r_placeholder: r})
    else:
      c = 0.0
    B[i] = c
  return B
```

You could potentially make this even more efficient by using a TensorFlow loop and making fewer calls to `sess.run()`, but the general principle is the same: reuse same the graph multiple times to get the benefit of TensorFlow.